# How to clear settings from vscode extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am building an extension in vscode. How can I clear all the settings in the `settings.json` after the extension is uninstalled or updated

```
export function deactivate() {
   vscode.workspace.getConfiguration("mysection").update("mykey",undefined,vscode.ConfigurationTarget.Global);

}
```

This doesn't work, the key still remain in `settings.json`

Comment: I don't know a single extension or program that does this. It's possible the user accidentally uninstalled it by misclicking. Nobody wants to lose their settings that way.

Comment: so are we suppose to keep our settings in the json even after the extension is removed?

Comment: Yes, why not? If the user wants to delete the settings to get rid of a token for example they could always edit the json file. Alternatively this could be a feature of VSCode itself so not every plugin developer has to implement the same thing.